# LINQ - Add to database does not show up

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I don't know why but in all tutorials I've seen there is `DBObject.TableObject.Add(newObject);`. I am not sure why but in my case there is no.

### Code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Post newPost)
{
    if (TryUpdateModel(newPost) == true)
    {
        string[] tagList = { "tag1", "tag2", "tag3"};
        _db.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(newPost);
        _db.SubmitChanges();


        foreach (string tag in tagList)
        {
            var newTag = new Tag();
            if (_db.Tags.Any(x => x.TagName == tag))
            {
                newTag = (from t in _db.Tags
                              where t.TagName == tag
                              select t).Single();
            }
            else
            {
                newTag = new Tag()
                {
                    TagName = tag
                };
            }

            // Does not work
            _db.Tags.Add(newTag);

            var postTag = new PostTag()
            {
                Tag = newTag,
                Post = newPost
            };

            // Does not work
            _db.PostTags.Add(postTag);
        }

        return Content(Convert.ToString(newPost.ID));
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
    else
    {
        return Content("Fail.");
    }
}
```

### Error

```
Error   1   'System.Data.Linq.Table<MvcApplication1.Models.Tag>' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.Table<MvcApplication1.Models.Tag>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Qmal\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Controllers\HomeController.cs   47  30  MvcApplication1
```

Reference? I have all LINQ references included, this is strange to me.

P.S.
I'm not eve sure if I'm doing it right, but still it is weird.

Comment: what tutorial are you looking at? do you want to use _db.Tags.InsertOnSubmit(newTag);
_db.CommitChanges()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking at older tutorials...the following should be what you need (instead of Add)

```
_db.Tags.InsertOnSubmit( newTag );
_db.SubmitChanges( );
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I thought I only can use InsertOnSubmit once per method. Anyway, maybe you have any tips on my code, I do it first time and not sure if it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, the problem is that the `Add` method you're using doesn't accept a parameter of type `System.Data.Linq.Table<MvcApplication1.Models.Tag>`.

By the looks of it the Add method is expecting a type of `Tag`. You could do something like:

```
newTag = (from t in _db.Tags
               where t.TagName == tag
                select t).Single()
                           .Select(m => new Tag(){
                             TagName = m.Name
                            });
```